# Can left handed people place a mezuzah on left side of doors

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, mezuzah, yoreh-deah, handedness

The basic halacha  is that a mezuzah should be placed on the right side of the door. My question is, if a person is left handed is it permissible for them to attach it to the left side of the door? Or does it make no difference whether they are left handed or right handed?

Comment: https://outorah.org/p/144876/

Comment: Could you elaborate (in the question) on why you think it permissible for left handed people to attach the _mezuzah_ to the left side of the door? The only place I know of where left handedness make a difference, is for the arm on which the _tefilin_ is put, and there it is learned from the wording of a biblical verse. Also, the _mezuzah_ is not there exclusively for the owner's personal use (and, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handedness#cite_ref-8), "[o]verall, around 90% of people are right-handed").

Comment: @shmosel That link probably should be made into a proper answer.

Comment: @TamirEvan There are many things customarily done with the dominant hand which we switch for lefties.

Comment: @shmosel "_There are many things customarily done with the dominant hand which we switch for lefties._" (1) If that is his assumption, I'd much prefer he be explicit about it. (2) I always got the impression that [right is almost always preferred (over left)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.3.4?lang=bi&lang2=en), regardless of ones dominant side, with the exception of _Tefilin_, and seemingly similar things, like the shoe lace tying order. IIRC (and it's been a long time since I saw it), I once saw an opinion that even left-handed people should tie their left shoe laces first.